# Put timestamp of file into a variable in CLI

Tags: variables, timestamp, command-line-interface

I need to get the timestamp of a file into a variable so that I can use it in the command line environment in Windows OS (to determine whether a file is older than 7 days).

Unfortunately I am stuck at the first hurdle of getting the files timestamp into a variable.

Can anyone lend a hand as to how to get the files time and date into a variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you using? "CLI" can refer to any language that runs through a console.

Comment: Apologies! Im using Windows OS!

Comment: So... it's just a `.bat` file?

Comment: Yes, I need to create the script in a .bat file